# Trouble Inserting a Image Data to LongBlob Field

Tags: php, mysql

Total newbie here, please bear with me.

Building a very small personal app that uploads some images and info. I can't figure out why the following PHP/MySQL doesn't add the last insert in the query (`$file_data`) to my DB's longblob field.

All the other fields in the query insert fine, meaning I tested them one at a time, adding to the query, until I got to the last and then the insert fails. I am able to echo `$file_data` before the insert and see that the data is there, I've also found that hardcoding a string value for `$file_data` (i.e `$file_data="this will insert"`) inserts fine... which is frustrating.

So my guesses are there's an error in the reading of the file (`$fp fread` etc) or that my longblob is setup wrong. File sizes are <16kb, so I'm sure it's not a php.ini issue either.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
$boxtype=$_POST['type'];
$title=$_POST['title'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_FILES['imgfile']['size'] > 0)
{

    $filename = $_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['imgfile']['size'];
    $mime_type = $_FILES['imgfile']['type'];        

    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $file_data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    fclose($fp);

    $query = "INSERT INTO table 
         (boxtype,title,filename,mime_type,file_size,file_data) 
         VALUES 
         ('$boxtype','$title','$filename','$mime_type','$file_size','$file_data')
         ";

    $db = db_connect(); 
    $result = $db->query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

    if ($result) 
    {
       echo "<br>Success<br>";
    }
}
else die("No Content");
```

MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `port` (
  `id` int(2) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `boxtype` tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `mime_type` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `file_size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_data` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Comment: what happens if you escape the data first before inserting? I've never used file uploads to database, so not sure if that's needed when inserting the $file_data in a field.

Comment: Apparently it is, I thought the same thing, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because its a binary, it probably contains values which means its probably throwing a wobble

Try using addslashes on the file_data variable, so it can save it.

Comment: This did the trick, didn't think escaping mattered outside of xxs attacks, but sure enough, the db didn't like the binary as is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The examples I came across while using Google showed that the data was escape either using addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string. Therefor my guess is that this is a crucial part since the $file_data string may contain various characters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the mysqli_ functions to create a prepared statement.  Here is an example

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Table(boxtype,title,filename,mime_type,file_size,file_data) 
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)';

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssib", $boxtype,$title,$filename,$mime_type,$file_size,$file_data);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

This will also prevent against SQL Injection attacks which it appears your code may be vulnerable to.  Alternatively, you can use the [PDO libraries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) to create prepared statements.

With PDO, you can do the following.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Table(boxtype,title,filename,mime_type,file_size,file_data) 
             VALUES (:boxtype,:title,:filename,:mime_type,:file_size,:file_data)';
$statement = $con->prepare($sql); 

$statement->bindParam(':boxtype',$boxtype,PARAM_STR); 
$statement->bindParam(':title',$title,PARAM_STR); 
$statement->bindParam(':filename',$filename,PARAM_STR); 
$statement->bindParam(':mime_type',$mime_type,PARAM_STR); 
$statement->bindParam(':file_size',$file_size,PARAM_INT); 
$statement->bindParam(':file_data',$file_data,PARAM_LOB); 
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If on windows use  `fopen($tmpName, 'rb');`  and use `mysql_escape_string($file_data)` .